# docker host pid mode doesn't work in swarm mode

Tags: docker, docker-swarm

I want a `container` to share `PID` namespace with host `OS` and I found `host PID mode` in `docker`.

> ### pid
>
> `pid: "host"`
>
> Sets the PID mode to the host PID mode. This turns on
>   sharing between container and the host operating system the PID
>   address space. Containers launched with this flag will be able to
>   access and manipulate other containers in the bare-metal machine’s
>   namespace and vise-versa.
>
> Referenced from https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#pid

It seems to work with `docker run` and `docker-compose up` but `swarm` mode, for example

```
$ docker run ---detach --pid=host ubuntu:16.04 tail -f /dev/null
$ docker exec -it container_name top
# Return all processes within host OS namespace.
```

---

```
##docker-compose.yml##
version: '3.4'

services:
    test:
        image: ubuntu:16.04
        command: tail -f /dev/null
        pid: host
```

---

```
$ docker-compose -f docker-compose.yml up -d
$ docker exec -it container_name top
# Return all processes within host OS namespace.
```

---

```
# there is only one manager node in the swarm(no another worker).

$ docker stack deploy -c docker-compose.yml test
$ docker exec -it container_name top 
# Return only container process namespace.
```

I know some options could not work as to `swarm mode`. However, in such case, as I know, the docker document always specify that, for instance, [container_name](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#container_name) option(See it is specifying that `container_name` won't work in `swarm` mode.).

> ### container_name
>
> .....
>
> .....
>
> Note: This option is ignored when deploying a stack in swarm mode with
>   a (version 3) Compose file.

My docker environment is `Docker 17.09.0-ce`, `docker-compose 1.17.0` on `Ubuntu16`. why doesn't `pid` mode work in `swarm` mode?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally, I opened an issue on [github](https://github.com/docker/cli) and I got the answer.

https://github.com/docker/docker.github.io/issues/5624

Answer (score 0):

The use of the host's PID namespace inside the container is not supported in docker swarm, via use of  `--pid=host` in swarm services. FYI, a patch that adds pid to the list of unsupported options so that a warning is printed has been pushed.

You can see this on https://github.com/docker/swarmkit/issues/1605

So with latest release of docker swarm, if you run the command:

```
$ docker stack deploy -c docker-compose.yml foobar
```

With `--pid=host` in it, you should get this warning:

> Ignoring unsupported options: pid

Stick with docker compose if you must use this feature.

https://www.aquasec.com/wiki/display/containers/Docker+Swarm+101 has additional information on Docker Swarm if you are interested.